AppleScript/Finder not finding the Numbers application
This fragment of a script does a simple check for the existence of Numbers in the Applications folder:
tell application "Finder"
  set AppFolder to folder "Applications" in startup disk as string
  set NumApp to AppFolder & "Numbers"
  set NumExists to (exists NumApp)
end tell

But it doesn't find it.  Numbers does exist:
vger:~(128)+>- ls -dl /Applications/Numbers.app/
drwxr-xr-x@ 3 root  wheel  96 18 Sep 13:33 /Applications/Numbers.app/
vger:~(129)+>-

So why does Finder/AppleScript think it doesn't?
This happens on macOS 14.x and 15.x.

You're not actually doing what you think you're doing. The value of 'NumApp' is not a reference to the application, rather, it is a string. So what you are probably testing for is whether the variable 'NumApp' exists. I can't say for certain because I think the result varies based on macos version and maybe whether you have 'show all filename extensions' enabled in the Finder preferences. The latter may be an issue because you don't include the full name of the application (ie including extension).

By the way, you can ask for the path to the applications folder on the startup disk directly, like so: path to applications folder as text.

Your first comment is a good observation.  As suggested by @wch1zpink I'm better off just trying to use Numbers (e.g. tell "Numbers" etc) in the script and handle any error.

You could also do something like id of application "/Applications/Numbers.app". If the application does not exist then it will generate an error. Alternatively, exists application "/Applications/Numbers.app", which is probably closest to your original approach.

If you're just trying to test whether the "Numbers' application is on the machine, use if exists application "Numbers" then …. Numbers in installed in the Applications folder by default, but even if it gets moved this will see it.

Combining the suggestions of @wch1pink, @Mockman and @Ted Wrigley here are two approaches:
set AppFolder to path to applications folder
set NumLoc to AppFolder & "Numbers.app" as string

try
    NumLoc as alias
    set NumExists to true
on error
    set NumExists to false
end try

The setting of the variable is just for illustration.  Or more directly:
if exists application "Numbers" then
    set NumExists to true
else
    set NumExists to false
end if


Using Finder to check if a file or folder or application exists, is not necessary.
Try something like this instead.
try
    alias "Macintosh HD:Applications:Numbers.app:"
on error errMsg number errNum
    display alert "Numbers.app doesn't exist in the Applications folder"
end try


Doesn't answer the question, in effect you're checking for its existence by a different route.  Interesting nevertheless, thanks.
